# .htaccess RewriteRule Doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i need to do bellow work: 
Source Address: http://myurl.com/news.php?s=searchkey 
Resault Address: http://myurl.com/searchnews/searchkey/ 
i Using This Code:

```
RewriteRule ^searchnews/(.*)/$ news.php?s=$1
```

but When i search in news.php, url not shown in Resault Format.
Note: i don't write any php code for this format and i using simple php code like this:

```
<?php
$sk=$_GET['s'];
$res=SearchNews($sk);
// Show Resault Rules
?>
```

What is My problem? i Should write some php code to get top url format?
this is my full htaccess Syntax:

```
<IFModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shownews/([0-9]+)/$ news.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^searchnews/(.*)/$ news.php?s=$1 [NC]
</IFModule>
```

Comment: I think the rule should work OK (if mod_engine is on, of course), but the query itself should refer to that `/searchnews/searchkey/` URL, not the one with `news.php`.

Comment: I assume the difference between `Searchnews` in the URL and `searchnews` in the rule is actually a typo in the question, right?

Comment: _but When i search in news.php, url not shown in Resault Format._ I may have misunderstood that part. But I believe that if you browsed to `/searchnews/something` then you would get `$sk` equal to `something`, no?

Comment: hi, my code is work success, but my question is: how display the **source url** in **resault url** format.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRules are case sensitive, but I see uppercase letter in your URL
Change URL to all-lowercase or use

```
RewriteRule ^searchnews/(.*)/$ news.php?s=$1 [NC]
```

if you want to stay with uppercase letters

Comment: The code looks correct. Did you get any specific error in response (501, 503)? Did you tried to output $_GET to check what you really get the expected values? Do you have mode_rewrite enabled in Apache? Seen any error in php_error log?

Comment: i found a solution, i use `RewriteRule ^search-news/(.*)/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/news.php?s=$1 [L, NC]` and its work success. how i can do this work without absolute domain address. have this way problem?

Comment: Please, update your .htaccess in question to actual one. I see now you use 'search-news' instead of 'searchnews'. Anything else have changed?